# Google Captcha with CI 3 app not working on production

Tags: codeigniter-3, recaptcha

I have added Google recapTCHA tickbox v2 on the login page of my codeignitor application and it was working perfectly on the local machine, however when i deploy my code on production enviornment it not working.

On my production machine, the tickbox Google Captcha works, however when i submit the form for Login it gives me error as:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Note: I have already added the domain in the recapTCHA admin site settings.

[image]

Before Login Form Submit Page is like this as:

[image]